# N-600 for a minor

Tags: citizenship, us-citizens, paperwork

My minor child has been approved their N-600 form. We were sent a notification to come and collect the certificate. Does the minor child need to come to the USCIS office or can we collect it on their behalf?

Comment: Is the child 14 years old or older?